# preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 20

Tags: laravel, vue.js

How to solve in laravel an vuejs, when I am trying to refresh the page I got such error message, this is my code from web file :

```
 preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 20
```

This is my Route:
I ma using laravel 8 php 7.4

```
Route::get('{path}',"HomeController@index")->where( 'path', '([A-z\d-\/_.]+)?' );
Route::get('{path}',"HomeController@index")->where('path','[-a-z0-9_\s]+');
```

Comment: `A-z` is likely your problem. Try `a-zA-Z` instead.

Comment: Try this `([A\-z\d\-\/_.]+)?' )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For php version is 7.3 and above use `\-` instead of `-`, so your final code :

```
Route::get('{path}',"HomeController@index")->where( 'path', '([A\-z\d\-\/_.]+)?' );
Route::get('{path}',"HomeController@index")->where('path','[\-a\-z0\-9_\s]+');
```